# Android Oreo notification keep making Sound even if I do not set sound. On Older version, works perfectly

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

So I am making my app compatible with Oreo and facing issue with notification.

I added notification channel according to documentation and everything is working smooth except notification keep making sound on every posting, tried setting defaults to 0 as well.

I am testing my app in emulator, any help is highly appreciated.

Used this code for creating channel

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(PlayerService.this, "channel_01")
                            .setAutoCancel(false)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setContent(viewsSmall)
                            .setCustomBigContentView(viewsExpanded)
                            .setDeleteIntent(pSwipeToDismiss);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
            }


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            /* Create or update. */
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_01",
                            "Playback Notification",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                    mBuilder.setChannelId("channel_01");
                }
    final Notification notification = builder.build();

                    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);
```

Comment: post all your code relative to your notification building please

Comment: Added complete code I am using to post notification

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Take a look at the notification channel settings (swipe your notification and press the settings icon under it and then select your channel). Those settings are set the first time you create the channel and then not modified unless you do it manually in the device (at least that is my experience from uninstalling and reinstalling my app to see what settings I get by default).

Basically, `channel.setSound(null, null)` *will only have effect when you create the channel on a fresh installation*. That might be what they try to explain in the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateChannel):

> Attempting to create an existing notification channel with its original values performs no operation

If you tried to follow that guide and set `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` and didn't use `channel.setSound(null, null)`, the channel would get importance level `Urgent Make sound and pop on screen` with the default sound.

Comment: Setting channel on fresh installation works for me Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

^Benjamin answer works but he is missing some important detail! You must change your channel ID each time you adjust your code or Oreo will not make the changes. Not sure why.

My code below and you can see where the chnage must be made with this <-------here

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        String channelID = "My Channel I";  <-------here
        String appName = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext );
        notificationCompatBuilder
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(mContext.getString(R.string.clocked_in))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
                .setChannelId(channelID)
                .setSound(null);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, appName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        notificationManager.notify(ONGOINGNOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompatBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: At https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels you can read: "After you create a notification channel, you cannot change the notification behaviors—the user has complete control at that point. Though you can still change a channel's name and description."

Answer (score 8):

Replace your code with this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                /* Create or update. */
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_01",
                "Playback Notification",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        mBuilder.setChannelId("channel_01");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My scene is the first time there is a sound, and the update notification does not require a sound.

I use this [setOnlyAlertOnce()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)) method

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Updating

Test pass version 26